# TimeoutInMinutes without nested stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there any way to specify a timeout such as [TimeoutInMinutes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-timeoutinminutes) for a CloudFormation template, but without nested stacks?

I would use TimeoutInMinutes but it requires you to specify a `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`, where you point to another template file that is uploaded on S3, and I want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: What about a `WaitCondition` that's being triggered by a custom resource?  The custom resource can depend on the last resource so it's last. It's a bit fragile, but might work.

Comment: Depending upon your use case, 'CreationPolicy' along with resource signal timeout might be worth looking at. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html